# SELECT COUNT with meekrodb Uncaught MeekroDBException

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, meekro

I would like to count the number of nums in a table from the associated idnr.
However, I get the following error message:
**Fatal error: Uncaught MeekroDBException: If you use named args, you must pass an assoc array of args!**

The table looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+-----------------------+
| idnr    |  nums   |  timestamp            |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+
| 1234    |  75     |  2021-10-19 11:59:22  |
| 1234    |  73     |  2021-11-09 11:59:22  |
| 1234    |  43     |  2020-07-19 12:59:22  |
| 4565    |  31     |  2021-11-19 13:59:22  |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+
```

The SQL string:

```
$results = DB::query("SELECT COUNT(nums) FROM tablename WHERE idnr = %i_idnr", '1234');
```

And I want to show it like:

```
echo $results['nums']; // the result should be 148
```

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your error describes itself.

From the [MeekroDB docs](https://meekro.com/docs/retrieving-data.html):

> You can pass an array of named parameters and access them by name.

Example code:

```
DB::query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name=%s_name AND age > %i_age AND height <= %d_height", 
  [
    'name' => $name,
    'age' => 15,
    'height' => 13.75
  ]
);
```

So in your case it would be:

```
$results = DB:: queryFirstRow(
    "SELECT SUM(nums) as nums_sum FROM tablename WHERE idnr = %i_idnr",
    ['idnr' => '1234']
);

echo $results['nums_sum'];
```

A few more notes:

1. You should use SUM(), otherwise you'll only rows count
2. Since it's an aggregating query which always returns a single row, use queryFirstRow instead of query
3. YOu should define an alias for SUM(nums), so it will be easier to retrieve data from the result array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) But where are the different to the string below? How can I show the result? Because when I write "echo $results;" then I get the Message: Warning:  Array to string conversion in...